# How to get all posts that are paid and public with ghost

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am trying to create custom pages example.com/free that get all free post and example.com/pro
that get all paid posts but I cannot solve it making this:

```
{{!< default}}

{{#post}}

<div class='c-archive'>
  <h1 class='c-archive__title'>{{ title }}</h1>
</div>

<div class='o-grid'>
  {{#get 'posts' filter="visibility:paid"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
      {{> post-card }}
    {{/foreach}}
  {{/get}}
</div>

{{/post}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution to get all paid post

```
{{!< default}}

{{#post}}

  <div class='c-archive'>
    <h1 class='c-archive__title'>Pro Lessons</h1>
  </div>

  <div class='o-grid'>
  {{#get 'posts'}}
    {{#foreach posts visibility='all'}}
      {{#has visibility="paid"}}
        {{> post-card-custom }}
      {{/has}}
    {{/foreach}}
  {{/get}}

  </div>

{{/post}}
```